# How to programatically disable the auto-focus of two webcams in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, directshow

i have big trouble calibrate two cameras and get the pose of them because of the autofocus. I am useing two logitech webcams of same type, openCV and C++.

I tried this:

```
cv::Size imageSize(1600,1200);      
cv::VideoCapture cap1(0);
cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,imageSize.width);
cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,imageSize.height);

cv::VideoCapture cap2(1);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,imageSize.width);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,imageSize.height);




IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl; 
HRESULT hr; 
if (hr == S_OK) {
  long defaultFocusValue = 0;
  hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Focus, // property 
                        defaultFocusValue, // value
                        CameraControl_Flags_Manual //Flag
                                ); 
}
```

Useing only one camera its working but with two - its not.

Who can help me out here?

Comment: How is this related to computer-vision ? You are only using a platform-dependent API to control a device-dependent parameter. OpenCV is doing nothing here. Nevertheless, I think the question is fine after you reduce it to its core: "How to programmatically control the auto-focus of two webcams using IAMCameraControl from DirectShow ?"

Comment: It's camera driver responsibility to properly support the properties. It is not clear whether you are doing it wrong, or this is supported wrong on the driver's end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **IAMCameraControl** interface is exposed on the DirectShow capture filter.  You're not showing how you've obtained this interface, but in general you would need to get a separate instance of this interface from each capture filter as in (C# code example):

```
IAMVideoProcAmp VideoProcAmp1 { get { return cap1 as IAMVideoProcAmp; } }
IAMVideoProcAmp VideoProcAmp2 { get { return cap2 as IAMVideoProcAmp; } }
```